# Write protect all SMB shares on macOS

Tags: macos, permission, smb

When using iOS 14 to browse SMB shares that reside on macOS 10.14 (Mojave) I am able to swipe to delete just about any listed item. This is a problem since there's no recycle bin mechanism when using SMB, and all deletions are final. It's too easy to make an irreversible mistake.

Since I log in to SMB with my regular admin account I am given access to every single volume on the machine, regardless of which folders are shared in the system's sharing settings. And even if I weren't, and I was only given access to write-protected folders, subfolders would still be writable.

Considering that I can't seem to use the simple sharing settings panel to configure this kind of access control, how would I go about treating every item as write-protected when accessed through SMB?

Would I need to create a regular user account just for safer SMB access, or can the SMB server be configured for this use case?

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the `File Sharing` tab under Sharing in System Preferences?

Comment: @Scottmeup Is there any particular details you're interested in?